# In EF 4.1, can I have DBSet<ISomething> instead of DBSet<Something>?

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, encapsulation, domain-model

I am trying to build a domain model with business methods and have EF 4.1 doing the persistence for me. So far so good.

Problem is, all properties are exposed as public on my domain classes. That's at least what I learnt from the tutorial anyway. That means, I have no strong proof that class properties won't change by some careless programmers outside of business methods. Encapsulation violated.

I tried introducing ISomething but TableAttribute applies only to classes, not interfaces, so I can't tell EF to do DBSet. If I leave TableAttribute to classes but make Something implement ISomething anyway then I can't do DBSet.Add() because EF doesn't know ISomething.

The only way I can think of is write a complete abstraction layer on top of EF 4.1 for CRUD using interfaces. Under the hood, do the type translation between Something and ISomething. It sounded a lot of complexity and a gaping hole in EF's design. Or I must've missed something.

How would you solve this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Problem is, all properties are exposed as public on my domain classes.
>   That's at least what I learnt from the tutorial anyway. That means, I
>   have no strong proof that class properties won't change by some
>   careless programmers outside of business methods. Encapsulation
>   violated.

How this will be solved by interface? Interface will again expose all properties as public and EF demands that property must have getter and setter.

EF is not able to work with interfaces. When using EDMX for mapping it is possible to play little bit with properties' accessibility but when using code first it is much worse because mapping is affected by the same accessibility rules. Creating abstraction layer on top of EF is mostly same as not using EF at all. Once you create abstraction you cannot use linq-to-entities directly and you will lose main reason for using EF.

Your problem is more about: Where is the boundary? If you want to work with entities only in business methods you should not expose them from these methods. If you want to make sure that properties are correctly handled perhaps you should implement validation logic directly into the entity.

Comment: Actually, I confused two issues a little bit in my question, my bad. The idea of using interfaces is such that I have a readonly interface (only getters) and an EF-backed read-write class. A thin layer on top of EF mediates the types. But type covariance quickly creeps in when dealing with dependent objects and things get hairy very quickly.

Comment: I do have validation logic directly in the entity. In fact, my business methods are on the entity, per classic OO. So, Person has Name, Age, Mood and CalculateMood(). Supposed I have a teenager instance his mood is going to be Bad. If some careless programmer changes Age=35 *after* CalculateMood() EF is going to diligently update in the database to age=35 and mood='Bad'. It is that corruption I want to prevent.

Comment: And if you're alluding to a business method class MoodHandler that loads a Person, reads Person.Age and then sets Person.Mood="Bad" then the problems are going to be 1) The domain model is anemic (Fowler, 2003) and 2) it still doesn't prevent the said careless programmer from changing Person.Age=35 after setting Person.Mood="Bad". Bear in mind that many business methods across classes are going to use the same Person instance in a transaction so the net effect is hard to predict and reason about, and cannot be easily unit-tested.

Comment: Isn't the point of validation to fire if anybody sets incorrect Age to person with given Mood? Anyway - there are two worlds. The world of theory where all that nice architectonic approaches and design patterns are defined and world of practice where EF is defined. Most of the time these two worlds don't work together very well. If you want to have code from the first world you will have to put very big effort to your solution or change persistence API.

Comment: Ok, I gave you an example where validation *could* catch the inconsistency, but you can easily imagine there are times when things cannot be validated: if I change age from 15 to 16, the fella is still going to be in Bad mood.

Comment: But I got the answer - EF doesn't allow me to do what I want. Which was why I was contemplating an abstraction layer on top.